# Operations Manager 2007

Tags: scom

i am looking for some custom scripts to pull information on perfomance data counters being collected by OpsMgr. Does anyone have any scripts they are currently using?

Comment: What language? .NET? Powershell?

Comment: wow, didn't think about the other options, but i was only thinking about t-sql with the idea of building some custom reports. but i suppose i would take whatever anyone has to offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some sql to get you started:

```
use operationsmanagerdw
SELECT TOP 100 pr.ObjectName, pr.CounterName, pri.InstanceName,
p.SampleValue
FROM Perf.vPerfRaw p
INNER JOIN vManagedEntity me ON me.ManagedEntityRowID =
p.ManagedEntityRowID
INNER JOIN vPerformanceRuleInstance pri ON pri.PerformanceRuleInstanceRowId
= p.PerformanceRuleInstanceRowId
INNER JOIN vPerformanceRule pr ON pr.RuleRowId = pri.RuleRowId
WHERE me.[Path] = 'server FQDN'
```

Works with SCOM 2007 SP1, SQL 2005 backend. Other performance tables in the data warehouse are Perf.vPerfHourly , and Perf.vPerfDaily

Comment: thanks Jim, this is a great start. i am going to mark this question as answered, but would love if others could share similar scripts.